# jQuery Function to parse a section of HTML

Tags: jquery, parsing

I am looking for a jQuery function to parse a section of HTML and read (store in a variable) from the first `<td>` inside the div class="appArea" and continue reading HTML until it reaches the table with a class of class="tb_pages", then stop.

I think I need an each() function but can't get it to work.

```
<div class="appArea">

<p class="cstmTitle">Team Wilson</p>
<table width="100%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr valign="top">
<td>

<p>
<p>We are proud to do our part to change the future and make a positive impact in the lives of others.</p>
<p><strong>Bullet List Ex</strong>:</p>
<ul>
<li>First</li>
<li>Second </li>
</ul>

<table class="tb_pages" border="0">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Bacon</th>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "_reading_"?

Comment: I think he means he has done too much console programming

Comment: What is an acceptable value using that html as the example?

Comment: Why not just use `$(".tb_pages")`

Comment: @SpYk3HH Because that wouldn't be the correct answer.

Comment: Did you find the answer you were looking for @meme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My 'solution' that's a little less ugly, but pays for it in efficiency:

```
var myHTML = "", isReading = false;

$(".appArea").children().each(function() {
    if(this.tagName == "td") isReading = true;
    else if($(this).hasClass("tb_pages") isReading = false;
    if(isReading) myHTML += $(this).html();
});
```

Or a solution using my favorite `if` shorthand, slightly more ugly but equally slightly more efficient:

```
var myHTML = "", isReading = false;

$(".appArea").children().each(function() {
    this.tagName == "td" && (isReading = true);
    $(this).hasClass("tb_pages") && (isReading = false);
    isReading && (myHTML += $(this).html());
});
```

---

Or an alternative to **iambriansreed**'s answer, using `slice()` instead of `split()` (should be slightly faster, but just as ugly):

```
var $fullHTML = $(".appArea").html()
var myHTML = fullHTML.slice(fullHTML.indexOf("<td>"), fullHTML.indexOf('<table class="tb_pages"'));
```

Comment: Nice. I think my `c` hits the nail on the head though.

Comment: Yeah I broke the line to help with readability. I had to do a pure jQuery grab to get the purist nazis off my back.

Answer (score 2):

Ugly:

```
var a = $('.appArea td:first').html().split('<table class="tb_pages"')[0];

var b = $('.appArea td:first').html().split(/<table(.*?)class="(.*?)tb_pages/)[0];
```

Pretty:

```
var c = $('div').append(
        $('.appArea td:first table.tb_pages').prevAll().clone()
    ).html();
```

Pick your poison.

Comment: Very nice, but will it blend? +1 :p

Comment: I think this is actually appropriate and the best you can do with jQuery for this question. The OP is treating the markup as a stream, rather than a tree; the scraped bit is not a logical DOM node.

Comment: I am sure some regex fans can help me tighten that up a bit.

Comment: Isn't this a classic case of "*don't try to parse html with regex*"?

Comment: @Ord ...so you pick `ugly1` then.

Comment: Well, that's equivalent to a regex. My point is that you could be tricked by, for example, `<table width="100%" border="0" class="tb_pages">`, or even by `<table class= "tb_pages">` (note the space after class=)

Comment: @Ord Feel free to "tighten that up a bit."

Comment: But you can't adequately "tighten that up a bit" with a regex. I think you should always handle html with a proper parser. In this case, I think you can handle everything from within jQuery. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.appArea td:first table.tb_pages').prevAll()
```

will get everything inside the td but before the tb_pages table.